# Asking for other inputs after piping a file to a perl script from a shell script

Tags: perl, pipe, stdin

I am working on a school project that involves having a main shell script that will prompt the user for a text file that contains 50 words.  If the shell script finds that file in the same directory as the shell and perl scripts, it will then print a menu asking if the user wants to sort the list using shell and outputting the sorted list to a new file (that one is finished and works), make a call to a perl script, where the perl script will take that file and print all the words in that file, then prompt the user for what word they want to search for.  This will return what line the word is on in the list.  What I have done is if the user selects to sort using the perl script, we pipe the inputted file in shell to the perl script with:

cat $filename | ./search.pl

Which happens to successfully pipe the file over to the perl script where we can use it.  The first while loop is where we access the list and print every word/line for the user to see, which works fine.  **But this is where I run into trouble.  After the whole list is printed, the printf line where it asks for the word they want to search for will print, but then the program will just stop without allowing anymore input, and go back to the terminal.**  What my logic for this search script is that we print every word for the user to see what they can search for, and then ask them what they want to search for, and then look through the inputted file from the shell script with a while loop; if we find it, print that we found it on that line, if we don't find it then go the to the next line, and if we hit the end without finding it just print that it can't be found.

**Why am I unable to enter more input with the call to STDIN and assign it to $word to use in the second while loop?**  Also, when I am doing the second while loop, is using <> by itself after asking for a different output going to mess things up?  If so, how do I make a reference again to the file for the second while loop?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$count = 1;    #global variable for return value
               # of words.

while (<>) {
    printf "$_";
}
#Now that we have opened the file, printed off everything for the user to see, they can now enter a     word in a prompt to
# see what line it is on.

printf "\nPlease enter the word you want to search for\n";
my $word = <STDIN>;
chomp $word;

while ( $line = <> ) {
    if ( $line =~ m/$word/ ) {
        print "$word has been found on line $count.\n\n";
    } elsif ( $line !=~ m/$word/ ) {
        $count++;
    } else {
        print "$word cannot be found.";
    }
}
```

The Shell script (for reference):

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
printf "Hello. \nPlease input a filename for a file containing a list of words you would like to use.      Please allow for one word per line.\n -> "
read filename
printf "You have entered the filename: $filename.\n"

if [ -f "$filename" ] #check if the file even exists in the current directory to use
then
    printf "The file $filename exists.  What would you like to do with this file?\n\n"
else
    printf "The file: $filename, does not exist.  Rerun this shell script and please enter a valid    file with it's proper file extension.  An example of this would be mywords.txt \n\nNow exiting.\n\n"
  exit
fi

printf "Main Menu\n"
printf "=========\n"
printf "Select 1 to sort file using Shell and output to a new file.\n"
printf "Select 2 to sort file using Perl and output to a new file.\n"
printf "Select 3 to search for a word using Perl.\n"
printf "Select 4 to exit.\n\n"

echo "Please enter your selection below"
read selection
printf "You have selected option $selection.\n"

if [ $selection -eq "1" ]
then
    read -p "What would you like to call the new file? "  newfile   #asks user what they want to call   the new file that will have the sorted list outputted to it
    sort $filename > $newfile
    echo "Your file: $newfile, has been created."
fi

if [ $selection -eq "2" ]
then
    read -p "What would you like to call the new file? "  newfile2
    cat $filename | ./sort.pl
    # > $newfile2   #put the sorted list into the new output file that the user specificed with    newfile2
fi

if [ $selection -eq "3" ]
then
    cat $filename | ./search.pl
fi

if [ $selection -eq "4" ]
then
     printf "Now exiting.\n\n"
     exit
fi
```

Comment: The first thing you need is `use strict;
use warnings;` at the top of your file. I think your problem is that `<>` is End of file when you do the second pass through it. A better solution would be to read the file once and put it into an array then look through the array

Comment: That would explain why it kept trying to put nothing into STDIN and the STDIN in the second while loop and not even running...

Comment: Even if I put it into an array, I still run into the problem where I ask for STDIN for the word, where it will still try to put EOF into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code as shown below. For your understanding, i have been putting comments but try to avoid comments wherever not required.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    
use strict;
use warnings;

#Input File passing as an argument to the program
my $InFile = $ARGV[0];

#Opening and reading a file using filehandle $fh
open my $fh,'<', $InFile or die "Couldn't open the file $InFile : $!"; 

while (<$fh>) {
    printf "$_";        
}

# Seek function as shown below will reset the file handle position to beginning of the file 
seek($fh, 0, 0);
printf "\nPlease enter the word you want to search for\n";
my $word = <STDIN>;
chomp $word;
my $count = 1; #global variable for return value of words               
my $val = 0;

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line =~ m/$word/) {
        print "$word has been found on line $count.\n\n";
        $val++;
    } 
    elsif ($line !~ m/$word/) {
        $count++;
    } 
}
if ($val == 0) {
    print "$word cannot be found";
} 

close($fh);
```

Comment: I tried your method and it's having issues on the line where we open my $fh.  

Use of uninitialized value $InFile in open at ./search.pl line 40.
Use of uninitialized value $InFile in concatenation (.) or string at ./search.pl line 40.
Couldn't open the file  : No such file or directory at ./search.pl line 40.

I thought it was initialized when it $InFile had the list passed to it.

Comment: Can you tell me the input file name that you are trying access ?

Comment: When you are running the program jus give as shown : perl filename.pl inputfilename  . Did you get me ?

Comment: I'm trying to access the filename, "filename".  In my shell script we prompt the user to enter a file.txt of their choice that exists in the directory, and we pass that to the perl script with:

cat $filename | ./search.pl

It's not a specific or hardcoded file that we want to open, it's whatever the user enters, so it could be called anything.

Comment: Are you implementing in unix environment ? I think from cat $filename will give the content of the file and that should be passed as an input to perl script right ?

Comment: I am using ubuntu on vmware, and it is passing the content as input to perl script, yes.

Comment: I guess what it's doing is trying to open the words from the list of words that were passed over instead of the file itself...I was thinking of going through each line of the list of words and assigning them to an array (as mentioned above), and just use the array to check the list for the word. But I would still run into issue when asking for the word using <STDIN> if I put the list of words into the array using STDIN beforehand.

Comment: Can you get me the shell script that you have . I think we can modify that and send the input file from shell as an argument to perl script. This may help us.

Comment: I have edited in the main shell script into my original post. It's below the search.pl script.

Comment: I figured it out!  We should have been bringing over the list with:

perl search.pl $filename

and with your convention I got it to work right away!  Thank you!